# Can I clip DirectX viewport into a single win32 control and use it together with other controls?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx

I was drawing triangles in D3D.

Doing that, I noticed that I always used the whole window for rendering and what if I want to create editor for something or 2D game engine or similar that requires GUI controls? Should I put separated dialog boxes that contain that controls (as shown on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBFAY.png)) or I should just clip this viewport into certain place on window or control such as on this example:
[image]

I tried to use static control handle for DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC::OutputWindow instead of main window handle and program crashed. And this made me very confused.

I didn't provide code because there are identical examples of initializing DirectX.

Comment: "I didn't provide code because there are identical examples of initializing DirectX." If that is true, the chances are high that your solution is already out there. If you want specific help you should provide at least a minimal executable example.

Comment: You can mix things with Direct2D. Direct2D can build a render target over an HDC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62775968/403671