# Win32 Button doesn't properly display in a Direct2D Window

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I have a Direct2D program, and my goal is to have a Win32 button rendered with the Direct2D window.

I was able to compile the program fine, but the problem is that *the button only shows when I click on it*. Once I click outside of the button, it just goes invisible. It's even invisible when I open the application. What I expect is for the button to be visible all the time. I'm not necessarily worried about if it renders above or below the Direct2D renderer.

When I click on it:

[image]

When I click outside the button (just blank):

[image]

Here is my render function:

```
create_drs(); // Creates device resources
m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(bg.r / 255, bg.g / 255, bg.b / 255, 1));
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
    L"BUTTON",
    L"a button",
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    0,
    0,
    150,
    150,
    m_hwnd,
    NULL,
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(m_hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);
m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
```

I've tried taking out the `Clear` function, but it's still invisible when the application opens, but stays visible forever once I click on it. I also tried looking online, but couldn't find a sufficient solution for this specific problem.

Comment: Creating a new button instance on every (re-)draw request is quickly going to have you run out of USER resources. That out of the way, I'm not sure you actually can render a common control on top of a Direct2D surface. The control needs to be a child window, presumably of the same window for which you created a render target. With that both will fight over who's rendering should make it to the display.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61915005/1889329). See [Direct2D and GDI Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-gdi-interoperation-overview) for more info. You'll still need to move the button creation code out of the rendering code. Creation of child controls is best done in a `WM_CREATE` message handler.

Comment: Did see that Q&A and didn't consider it because I wanted to use _ID2D1HwndRenderTarget_, but seems like it's the (only?) way to get my problem solved. Anyways, tried it and it works great, thanks for your help.