can not see the EDIT control but can use it If I use ID2D1DeviceContext to clear the window?
I can create EDIT in winapi and If I want to draw something the EDIT will be covered?
If I delete swapChain->Present1(1, 0, &parameters); it will be ok.
(if I just use ID2D1HwndRenderTarget to do the same thing it is all ok.).
this is the code:
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"
#include<d2d1.h>
#include<d2d1_1.h>
#include<D2DErr.h>
#include<d3d11.h>
#include<dxgi1_2.h>
#include<Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d2d1.lib")


ID3D11Device* device = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx = NULL;

IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice = NULL;
IDXGIDevice1* dxgiDevice_1 = NULL;
IDXGIFactory2* dxgiFactory = NULL;


ID2D1Factory* factory = NULL;
ID2D1Device* d2dDevice = NULL;
ID2D1DeviceContext* context = NULL;

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = { 0 };
IDXGISwapChain1* swapChain = NULL;

HWND hwnd = 0;

DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters{};




WNDPROC editProc = NULL;
LRESULT APIENTRY EditSubClassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_CHAR) {
        WCHAR ch = (WCHAR)wParam;
    }
    return CallWindowProc(editProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void init_x(HWND h) {
    hwnd = h;
    UINT flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 };
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, flags, featureLevels, ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, &featureLevel, &ctx);
    IDXGIDevice1* dxgiDevice = NULL;
    hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice1), (void**)&dxgiDevice);
    hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory);
    hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&dxgiDevice);
    hr = D2D1CreateDevice(dxgiDevice, nullptr, &d2dDevice);
    hr = d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, &context);
    swapChainDesc.Width = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Height = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    IDXGIAdapter* dxgiAdapter = NULL;
    hr = dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&dxgiAdapter);
    hr = dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), (void**)&dxgiFactory);
    hr = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(device, hwnd, &swapChainDesc, nullptr, nullptr, &swapChain);
    hr = dxgiDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice1), (void**)&dxgiDevice_1);
    hr = dxgiDevice_1->SetMaximumFrameLatency(1);
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer = NULL;
    hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&backBuffer);
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 properties1 = D2D1::BitmapProperties1(D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
        96.0f, 96.0f);
    IDXGISurface* dxgiBackBuffer = NULL;
    hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(IDXGISurface), (void**)&dxgiBackBuffer);
    ID2D1Bitmap1* renderTargetBitmap;
    hr = context->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(dxgiBackBuffer, &properties1, &renderTargetBitmap);

    context->SetTarget(renderTargetBitmap);


    context->BeginDraw();
    context->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(1, 1, 0, 1));
    context->EndDraw();

    swapChain->Present1(1, 0, &parameters);

    HWND hTextBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_BORDER, static_cast<int>(15), static_cast<int>(15), static_cast<int>(130), static_cast<int>(30), hwnd, (HMENU)50, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm{};
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);
    SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(ncm), &ncm, 0);
    editProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hTextBox, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)EditSubClassProc);

}

and this is the full example https://github.com/ljzj2/testedit

Use something like imgui instead, otherwise you will have to repaint the edit control on every frame on the CPU, which will be super slow.

You can combine Direct2D and GDI, but not with the type of code you have wich prempts the whole HWND. Official doc is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-gdi-interoperation-overview and here is a sample that demonstrates it https://stackoverflow.com/a/62775968/403671

but why can not use  ID2D1DeviceContext? someone tell me ID2D1HwndRendertarget is old version.

When you have an Direct2D render target, you can always call QueryInterface on it for an ID2DDeviceContext

I mean if I use render target it is all ok. but If I use ID2D1DeviceContext the EDIT control will be covered. I can not see it. @SimonMourier

We're ok it cannot with the code you have but I can work. Have you read the links I posted?

@SimonMourier I read it. I just wonder why swipchain will make it not work. if use ID2D1DeviceContext which get from ID2D1HwndRenderTarget it is ok. but If I create ID2D1DeviceContext using this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts  ID2D1DeviceContext will do cover the EDIT control.

@lescper The doc already said: ID2D1HwndRenderTarget won't work with Windows Store apps with windows 8. It didn't use another device context. That's why it doesn't cover the edit control.

@Torrecto-MSFT then I use ID2D1DeviceContext which is queryInterface by ID2D1HwndRenderTarget will work with windows store with windows8?

@lescper Yes! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts#rendering-with-direct2d-on-windows-8 It says: starting with Windows 8, we do not recommend rendering by using methods that rely on interfaces like ID2D1HwndRenderTarget because they won't work with Windows Store apps. So it may have exceptional behavior when you use it.

@lescper Not just upvote. Could you accept it? Thank you! ;)

Just make a conclusion of Rendering with Direct2D on Windows 8
On Windows 7 and earlier, you use a ID2D1HwndRenderTarget or another render target interface to render to a window or surface. Starting with Windows 8, we do not recommend rendering by using methods that rely on interfaces like ID2D1HwndRenderTarget because they won't work with Windows Store apps. You can use a device context to render to an Hwnd if you want to make a desktop app and still take advantage of the device context's additional features. However, the device context is required to render content in a Windows Store apps with Direct2D.
